# Configuring .eslintrc

Tags: eslint

I ran the command `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` after installing the eslint package. But the first line after setting up the configuration which is `module.exports` gives the following warning 
**file will be ignored by default**.

I'm unable to implement my custom rules.Need assistance with configuring my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is saying that ESLint will not lint the contents of `.eslintrc.js` by default. It'll still read the configuration just fine. If you want ESLint to check the code style of `.eslintrc.js`, you can create a file named `.eslintignore` with the contents `!.eslintrc.js`.